# Delayed handling of Matplotlib's 'close_event' when using tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

While trying to implement a interactive figure (i.e., the user can select some points on the figure, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77534673/how-to-exit-the-event-loop-when-a-figure-created-using-matplotlib-is-manually-cl) for the whole description) I run into some issues while handling the close events. When the function is called as is, no issue happens. However, calling it from tkinter seems to introduce a delay in the catching of the 'close_event' caught by `fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', event_handling)`.

This results in two issues:

1. The closure of the figure is delayed until the event is caught and so even though the script went through a `plt.close()` call.
2. When the Figure is being drawn multiple times (i.e., the call to the function wrapping the figure is imbedded in a loop), the delayed 'close_event' which should have been caught and applied during the first iteration 'appears' in the next iteration thus triggering the action associated to such an event.

Note that the issue only appears when Tkinter is used, simply looping over the function will not produce this behaviour.

Below is an example showcasing the issue. The 3 lines in `main()` can be replaced by a direct call to `easy_plot()` (be it in a loop or a standalone call) to observe the difference.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys

import traceback as tb
import time

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


# Just a function to refresh the title
def tellme(s):
    plt.title(s, fontsize=13)
    plt.draw()

# Figure closing event -> the flag value is changed to 1, allowing the script to exit the loops
def close_event(event):
    global close_flag
    close_flag = 1
    print('---------> I caught a close event <---------')

# Key pressing event -> linked to close the figure when the user press <Enter>
def key_event(event):
    if event.key == 'enter':
        global key_event_end
        key_event_end = 1
    else:
        print(' ----> A key event was caught: You pressed the <{}> key'.format(event.key))



def easy_plot():
    # Pre-defining the flags    
    global close_flag
    close_flag = 0
    
    global key_event_end
    key_event_end = 0
    
    # Defining some data points
    x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi*5, 0.1)
    
    fig, axs = plt.subplots()
    
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', close_event) # Connect to the figure, if closed the event will be triggered
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', key_event) # Connect to the figure, if a key is pressed the event will be triggered
    
    
    axs.plot(x, np.sin(x))
    
    
    
    # Event loop
    while close_flag == 0:
        update_title = True
        
        # Title is only updated once in this example
        if update_title:
            tellme('Title is updated, press enter to close the Figure')
            update_title = False  
            
        if plt.waitforbuttonpress(0.1):
            print()
            print('A button was pressed')
            print('close_flag: {}'.format(close_flag))
            print('key_Event_end: {}'.format(key_event_end))
            

        # Check if the Figure was closed or if the user confirmed it want to exit the loop
        if close_flag == 1 or key_event_end == 1:
            break
            
        # Check if the Figure was closed or if the user confirmed they wanted to exit the loop
        if close_flag == 1 or key_event_end == 1:
            break
        
        
        time.sleep(0.1)
        
    print()
    print('Last print before removing the values')
    print('close_flag: {}'.format(close_flag))
    print('key_Event_end: {}'.format(key_event_end))
    
    plt.close()
    del key_event_end
    del close_flag
    del fig
    del axs
    print()
    print('Figure was closed and related variables were deleted')
    print()
    print('---------')
    print('Exiting the function')
    print('---------')
    print()



class Interface:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title = 'Testing frame'
        
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self.root, padding=(3, 3, 12, 12))
        self.frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.W, tk.E, tk.S))
        
        ttk.Button(self.frame, text='Exit', command=self.root.destroy).grid(column=1, row=1)
        ttk.Button(self.frame, text='One iter', command=self.one_iteration_button).grid(column=2, row=1)
        ttk.Button(self.frame, text='N iter', command=self.n_iteration_button).grid(column=3, row=1)


    def one_iteration_button(self):
        print('--- Starting the plot with one iteration ---')
        easy_plot()
        print()
        print('--- Out of the plot function ---')


    def n_iteration_button(self):
        print()
        print('--- Starting the plot with 2 iterations ---')
        for ii in range(2):
            print()
            print('--- Currently ploting iteration {} ---'.format(ii))
            easy_plot()
            print()
            print('--- Out of the plot function ---')
            print()



def main():
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    myInterface = Interface(root)
    root.mainloop()
    



if __name__ == "__main__":    
    try:
        main()
        print('I am out of main')
        sys.exit(0)
        
    except Exception as err:
        # Catching the exception        
        message = ''.join(tb.format_exception(None, err, err.__traceback__))
        
        # Print the traceback and exit the script
        print(message)
        
        # Exiting the script
        sys.exit(0)
```

By looking at the prints coming out, we can see that the 'close_event' is only caught after the scripts exited the `easy_plot()` function resulting in `close_event()` (the function, not the event itself) being triggered when the next figure is drawn.

All of this said, there are a few points I don't understand and would like to clarify:

1. How come `plt.close()` doesn't trigger the `close_event` right away as it does when Tkinter is not used?
2. Why (and how is it possible?) is the last 'close_event' triggered while we are already out of the function?
3. The figure is closed and its container is deleted when the script exit the function, thus how can it impact what is happening later on in the script?

Although I expected some changes in behaviour when Matplotlib is used with Tkinter, I didn't expect it would affect the handling of events this much.

I am open to any suggestion to understand what is happening.

I am using Python 3.12.0, Matplotlib 3.8.0 and Tkinter 8.6.13

**EDIT:** Creating a new thread and binding the plot function to it seems to solve the issues. This, however, seems more like a quick and dirty patch rather than an actual fix. Still open to any suggestion though