# Matplotlib Zoom Subplot Separately

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Newbie to Matplotlib

There is a dated discussion on how to zoom a scatter plot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551049/matplotlib-plot-zooming-with-scroll-wheel) which is very handy.

I tried a little hack to change the code to display 2 separate scatter plots.
I modified the code to have two scatter plots and instantiate the class ZoomPan to each of the plots. The Pan function works fine -- I can choose to pan either plot without affecting the other. However, when I move my mouse to one scatter plot and use the mouse wheel to zoom the plot. Both plots zoom in and out together.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

class ZoomPan:
    def __init__(self,ax):
        self.press = None
        self.cur_xlim = None
        self.cur_ylim = None
        self.x0 = None
        self.y0 = None
        self.x1 = None
        self.y1 = None
        self.xpress = None
        self.ypress = None
        self.ax = ax

    def zoom_factory(self, base_scale = 2.):
        def zoom(event):
            ax = self.ax
            
            cur_xlim = ax.get_xlim()
            cur_ylim = ax.get_ylim()

            xdata = event.xdata # get event x location
            ydata = event.ydata # get event y location

            if event.button == 'down':
                # deal with zoom in
                scale_factor = 1 / base_scale
            elif event.button == 'up':
                # deal with zoom out
                scale_factor = base_scale
            else:
                # deal with something that should never happen
                scale_factor = 1
                print(event.button)

            new_width = (cur_xlim[1] - cur_xlim[0]) * scale_factor
            new_height = (cur_ylim[1] - cur_ylim[0]) * scale_factor

            relx = (cur_xlim[1] - xdata)/(cur_xlim[1] - cur_xlim[0])
            rely = (cur_ylim[1] - ydata)/(cur_ylim[1] - cur_ylim[0])

            ax.set_xlim([xdata - new_width * (1-relx), xdata + new_width * (relx)])
            ax.set_ylim([ydata - new_height * (1-rely), ydata + new_height * (rely)])
            ax.figure.canvas.draw()

        ax = self.ax
        self.ax.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event',zoom)
        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', zoom)
        
        return zoom

    def pan_factory(self):
        def onPress(event):
            ax = self.ax
            if event.inaxes != ax: return
            self.cur_xlim = ax.get_xlim()
            self.cur_ylim = ax.get_ylim()
            self.press = self.x0, self.y0, event.xdata, event.ydata
            self.x0, self.y0, self.xpress, self.ypress = self.press

        def onRelease(event):
            ax = self.ax
            self.press = None
            ax.figure.canvas.draw()

        def onMotion(event):
            ax = self.ax
            if self.press is None: return
            if event.inaxes != ax: return
            dx = event.xdata - self.xpress
            dy = event.ydata - self.ypress
            self.cur_xlim -= dx
            self.cur_ylim -= dy
            ax.set_xlim(self.cur_xlim)
            ax.set_ylim(self.cur_ylim)

            ax.figure.canvas.draw()

        ax = self.ax
        fig = ax.get_figure() # get the figure of interest

        # attach the call back
        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',onPress)
        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event',onRelease)
        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event',onMotion)

        #return the function
        return onMotion

def setscatter(scatter_label,ax):
    ax.set_title(scatter_label)
    x,y,s,c = numpy.random.rand(4,200)
    s *= 200
    ax.scatter(x,y,s,c)
    scale = 1.1
    zp = ZoomPan(ax)
    zp.zoom_factory(base_scale=scale)

def main():
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2)
    setscatter('ax',axs[0])
    setscatter('bx',axs[1])
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried to dig a bit inside the code and I wonder if I can attach the call back functions to individual subplot instead to the figure itself

```
    self.ax.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event',zoom)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', zoom)
```

It seems there is no such method .canvas for a subplot and I couldn't wrap my head around to find a way to pass the current inaxes to the class when the zoom function is triggered as in the example shown [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/figure_axes_enter_leave.html).

I realized that the original discussion has been dated for a while. Maybe there are new features in Matplotlib can achieve the same.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to dig a bit inside the code and I wonder if I can attach the call back functions to individual subplot instead to the figure itself.

You cannot. However, you can employ the same logic used at the start of `onPress` such that the function body of `zoom` is only executed if the cursor is within the axis limits:

```
def zoom(event):
    ax = self.ax
    if event.inaxes != ax: return 
    ...
    # rest of function
```